# write a simple batchfile with If query with wmic.exe

Tags: batch-file, wmic

i have 3 different PC models, I want to deploy a script to those 3 models. the script run wmic query and check the PC model and when it match to one of those it go to a path and install application.
I am testing the below script, But could not make it work

This is normal text

```
    @for /f "tokens=*" %%m in ('wmic computersystem get model /value ^| find 
   "="') do set %%m
    @echo %Model%

  If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 840 G3" then Goto:840G3
  If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 840 G4" then Goto:840G4
  If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 850 G4" then Goto:850G4
   Goto WrongModel

  :840G3
  ping google.com

  Goto END

  :840G4
 ping yahoo.com

  Goto END

   :850G4
  timeout /t 100

  Goto END

   :END
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I could not make it work, i wont run anything

Comment: Unless you provide a clear description what you want your script to do and what it actually does it is quite hard to help you, don't you think?

Comment: You're using the `Find` command to filter on `=`, instead of a common required match, _(perhaps `HP EliteBook 8`)_. Then again, the `WMIC` command allows a `WHERE` option some useful operators, which would be preferable to filtering the result later with `Find`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was the word 'then'

Try your script like this instead:

```
If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 840 G3" Goto:840G3
If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 850 G4" Goto:850G4
If "%Model%" == "HP EliteBook 840 G4" Goto:840G4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a replacement for your provided lines `1-7` according to my comments:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=3-4" %%A In ('WMIC ComputerSystem Where^
 "Model='HP EliteBook 840 G3' Or Model='HP EliteBook 840 G4' Or^
 Model='HP EliteBook 850 G4'" Get Model 2^>Nul') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In (
    "%%A%%B") Do GoTo %%C 2>Nul
```